# Issue with class methods in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm following an edx course on Python and we creating a class for simple encryption of letters.

The following method works and gets full marks.

```
def apply_shift(self, shift):
    '''
    Applies the Caesar Cipher to self.message_text with the input shift.
    Creates a new string that is self.message_text shifted down the
    alphabet by some number of characters determined by the input shift        

    shift (integer): the shift with which to encrypt the message.
    0 <= shift < 26

    Returns: the message text (string) in which every character is shifted
         down the alphabet by the input shift
    '''
    y=self.build_shift_dict(shift)
    xnew=''
    for a in self.message_text:
     if a in y:
      xnew=xnew+y[a]
     else:
      xnew=xnew+a 
    return(xnew)
```

There are getter methods for self.message_text in particular

```
def get_message_text(self):
    '''
    Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class

    Returns: self.message_text
    '''
    return self.message_text
```

however when i replace self.message_text in for loop of the code with self.get_self_message i get the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submission.py", line 191, in apply_shift
    for a in self.get_message_text:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

If i use the class name infront which is Message and try
Message.get_message_text(self) this works, we've been taught that when we assign an object to a name for example c then i can use c.get_message_text() to access it can i not use self.get_message_text() this way in the code or does this only work for outside the code? In which case it needs to be Message.get_message_text(self)?

Comment: Are you sure you're invoking the method (that is, using parentheses after the method name) when referencing `self.get_message_text`? (So your code ought to be `for a in self.get_message_text():`) The error message seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: And otherwise, having a "get_message_text"  method as it is presented here is a complete anti-pattern in Python - to the point I doubt the quality of the course you are following.  Maybe you have other course options?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the responses they were very helpful! I wasn't adding the parenthesis at the end. So to be clear if i'm going to invoke the method in the code i need the paranthesis but if i'm defining things using self.get_message_text then i don't need the paranthesis?